# Is it mandatory to instantiate a List (using Arraylist) in JAVA?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, instantiation

Is it mandatory to instantiate a List using Arraylist in JAVA to perform some operations on it?

Can I do something like this:

```
List<WebElement> rows=htmltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

Will this work?

Where I am not instantiating the List like :

```
List<WebElement> rows = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
```

and then going for getting the values to the variable "rows" by:

```
rows = htmltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

What is the difference between the two approaches mentioned above? If I do one more step of instantiating "rows" and then getting values to it?

Answer (score 1):

To work with an actual object you need, well, an actual object, not just a null reference. How you obtain this object, eg. by instantiating it yourself, as a parameter or as a return value from some other method, doesn't matter.

> List rows=htmltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); //Will
>   this work?

If `htmltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"))` returns a `List<WebElement>` object, then yes, it will work.

> "What is the difference between the two approaches mentioned above?"

Creating a new instance will, well, create a new independent instance (in the case of ArrayList: an empty list object). If you're getting an object from a method, then it's the responsibilty of that method to create or get the object. It allows to reuse objects in different methods by passing their object references. In your case you would work with the WebElement list object of your htmltable. If this makes sense in your use case or if you need to work with a new, fresh instance, only you can tell. You also have to consider if you need to manipulate the list, if this is possible with returned list (is it unmodifiable?) and what would the effect be to your htmltable.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please answer this also :  "What is the difference between the two approaches mentioned above?"  that is doing one more step and instantiating it and then getting values to the list. Is there any difference ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> rows=htmltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); //Will this work?
```

It will work, if htmltable finds a List objekt. At some point it must have been initialized. If you do

```
List<WebElement> rows = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
```

first, does not matter. It will get overwritten by the result of the method from htmltable.